# React Native Typescript Formik typings of handleSubmit in onPress

Tags: typescript, forms, react-native, typescript-typings, formik

I just started a project on React Native with Typescript and came along Formik in order to build form in my application.

I did the great [formik tutorial guide](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/tutorial) and saw the use of [formik with RN section in JS](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/react-native).

However, when I tried to translate this example into typescript, then I got the following typing error on the `Button's onPress attribute`:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<ButtonProps>): Button', gave the following error.
    Type '(e?: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(ev: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeTouchEvent>) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'e' and 'ev' are incompatible.
        Type 'NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeTouchEvent>' is not assignable to type 'FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>'.
          Types of property 'nativeEvent' are incompatible.
            Type 'NativeTouchEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'Event': bubbles, cancelBubble, cancelable, composed, and 17 more.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ButtonProps, context?: any): Button', gave the following error.
    Type '(e?: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(ev: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeTouchEvent>) => void'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(6926, 5): The expected type comes from property 'onPress' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Button> & Readonly<ButtonProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'
index.d.ts(6926, 5): The expected type comes from property 'onPress' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAt...
```

From what I understand, the `handleSubmit` function `(e?: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => void`, accepts an event from a form submission (`onSubmit` attribute of a `form` element). Since there is no Form equivalent in RN, it complains receiving the `(ev: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeTouchEvent>) => void` from the `RN Button's onPress` attribute.

In order to get rid of the error and keep going, I used this following workaround which I'm not satisfied with :

```
 <Button
              title="Do it !"
              color={colors.red}
              onPress={
                (handleSubmit as unknown) as (
                  ev: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeTouchEvent>
                ) => void
              }
/>
```

I'd like to know how should I solve this typing error properly.

[CodeSandbox: App.tsx:32](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-web-ts-dwll4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can describe your type like: `(event: GestureResponderEvent) => void;`

[Code sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzD0o.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<Button 
onPress={e => handleSubmit(e as unknown as FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>)}
title="Submit"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this:

```
<Pressable onPress={(e:any) => formik.handleSubmit(e)}>
```